# I can't seem to get the IF condition I'm looking for

Tags: mysql, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, vbulletin

I have the function working properly, I just cant seem to get the right IF condition to wrap it all in.  What I am trying to achieve is only create the link list IF the WHILE has anything to display.

so if I'm on thread id 3 and it has 2 addon thread ids 4,5 it will create:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="showthread.php?t=4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="showthread.php?t=5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

if I'm on thread 2 and it has no addon thread ids it should return nothing.

This is what I currently have with no conditions.

```
$addonid = $db->query_read ("
  SELECT drc.threadid AS threadid
  FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "modsys_settings` AS drc
  LEFT JOIN `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread` AS thread
  ON(drc.mod_addons=" . $threadinfo['threadid'] . ")
  WHERE thread.threadid IN (" . $threadinfo['threadid'] . ")
");
  $post['addons'] = '<ul>';

  while ($addons = $db->fetch_array ($addonid)) {    
    $ci_counter = $db->query_read ("
      SELECT drc.mod_addons AS addon, drc.threadid, thread.threadid AS threadid, thread.title AS threadtitle
      FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "modsys_settings` AS drc 
      LEFT JOIN `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread` AS thread ON(drc.mod_addons=" . $threadinfo['threadid'] . ") 
      WHERE thread.threadid IN (" . $addons['threadid'] . ")
    ");

    $counter = $db->fetch_array ($ci_counter);
    $post['addons'] .= '<li><a href="showthread.php?t=' .   $addons['threadid'] . '">'. $counter['threadtitle'] .'</a></li>';
  }

  $post['addons'] .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like `$addonid->num_rows` ?

```
$show_list = $addonid->num_rows;
if($show_list)
     $post['addons'] = '<ul>';
```

And then after the while

```
if($show_list)
    $post['addons'] = '</ul>';
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks!

Comment: I gave this a try using

    $show_list = $addonid->num_rows;
     if($show_list){
        $post['addons'] = '<ul>';
      }

and it actually doesnt show the <ul> at all =/  (cant get ctrl k to work lol)

Comment: i had to adapt it for the software I'm developing for but I got it =)  $show_list = $db->num_rows ($addonid)

Answer (score 1):

I dont play much with php, so I will give you general guidelines.

Just use a boolean variable to control when create the init tag and close it.

```
 @i_create_a_tag = false;

 while ( something ) {
     -- open the tag only once
     if (!@i_create_a_tag) {
         $post['addons'] = '<ul>';
         @i_create_a_tag = true;
     }

     ....          
 }

 -- close the tag if was open
 if (@i_create_a_tag) {
    $post['addons'] = '</ul>';
 }
```

Comment: I also tried this and @ gave me "syntax error, unexpected '=' " so I replaced with $ and still no <ul>